# Перехват исключения из функции setTimeout, выполняемой внутри экземпляра объекта Promise

Tags: javascript, settimeout, catch

Уважаемые участники, подскажите пожалуйста решение.

В этом блоке кода метод catсh прекрасно перехватывает исключение:

```
const myPromise = new Promise(() => {
  throw new Error(`Упс! Бросили исключение.`);
});

// Перехватываем исключение в методе `catch`.
myPromise
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

А в этом блоке метод catсh не будет вызван:

```
сonst TIMEOUT = 1000;

const mySecondPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error(`Ошибка в асинхронной функции`);
  },
  TIMEOUT
  );
});

mySecondPromise
  .catch(() => console.log(`Этот код не будет выполнен`));
```

Поясните пожалуйста:

1. Почему так происходит (предполагаю, что это связано с Event Loop)?
2. Как переписать код так, чтобы перехват исключения в методе catch работал с setTimeout?

Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Потому что setTimeout занимается только тем, что откладывает выполнение функции на потом и успешно завершает свою работу, соответственно и промис успешно отрабатывает, ведь никаких ошибок в процессе создания промиса не возникло. Чтобы после этого промис зафейлился, нужно вызвать функцию reject, но так как её никто не вызывает, он навсегда остаётся в состоянии pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере мы явно должны указать на исключении с помощью reject

```
const testF = () => { throw new Error(`Упс! Бросили исключение.`) }

const genPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        try {
            const res = testF()
            resolve(res)
        } catch (e) { reject(e) }
    }, 1e3)
})

t1: {
    const log = console.log.bind(console, 't1:')
    const _then = log.bind(console, 'then:')
    const _catch = log.bind(console, 'catch:')

    genPromise()
        .then(_then)
        .catch(_catch)
        .then(_then)
}

t2: {
    const log = console.log.bind(console, 't2:')
    const _then = log.bind(console, 'then:')
    const _catch = log.bind(console, 'catch:')

    void async function () {
        let pRes = null
        try {
            pRes = await genPromise()
        } catch (e) {
            _catch(e.message)
        }
        _then(pRes)
    }()
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за примеры кода. Это интересно. Конструкция  try..catch подходит. Особенно мне понравилась идея привязки контекста консоли - делает код чище. Я нашел еще одно решение. Определяем функцию-исполнитель: ```const someFunction = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));``` и вызываем: ```someFunction(timeout).then(() => doSomething()).catch(() => console.log(`This code will not be executed`));```а если в асинхронной функции происходит исключение: ```someFunction(timeout).then(ErrorEvent).catch(() => console.log(`This code will not be executed`));```